# How do I let the user choose half stars when using a RatingControl in UWP?

Tags: c#, uwp

I would like to present the user with 5 stars and have them be able to choose 3.5 stars. I can see that I can set the placeholder value to 3.5 and it displays properly but when moving the mouse over the stars they select only whole values. Is there a way to let the user select partial stars with the UWP RatingControl?

Comment: Can you please share the  code snippet also of what you have done so far? If would be easier for others to help in that way and it's also as per the guidelines

Comment: When you set the placeholder value to 3.5, RatingControl internally will calculate and display based on the value you pass in. But when you try to click it by using the mouse, it is designed that you can only select the whole star, so currently, there is no api can select partial stars with the RatingControl.